# single word noun for somebody who is unfaithful to their spouse / relationship-partner

Tags: single-word-requests

There seems to be a range of adjectives to describe such people, and the noun for such an action is **infidelity**, but I couldn't find a noun that can be commonly used to describe the *unfaithful person.*

> he/she has been cheating on his/her spouse/partner, he/she is a __________

(This train of thought was prompted by somebody's garbled answer here that was giving an example involving infidelity.)

Please note: 'adulterer/ adulteress' is an obvious option, but its legal definition presupposes marriage, at least here in India, so I should like to find some other word to fit this question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61035/discussion-on-question-by-english-student-single-word-noun-for-somebody-who-is-u).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To my mind the most descriptive idiom is **two-timer**, the noun form of **two-time**

> [- to be unfaithful to (a lover or spouse)
>
>    - to double-cross.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/two-timer)

Comment: But this does not cover the general case when the unfaithful cad may have a whole string of partners and be an n-timer.

Comment: @KalleMP he's a two-timer for every single pair

Answer (score 6):

> **Philanderer**/ noun form to describe one who philanders
>
> Philander
> [fi-lan-der]
> verb (used without object)
>
> 1. (of a man) to make love with a woman one cannot or will not marry; carry on flirtations.

or

> **Debauchee**
> [deb-aw-chee, -shee]/
> noun
>
> 1. a person addicted to excessive indulgence in sensual pleasures; one given to debauchery.

or

> **Reprobate**
> [rep-ruh-beyt]/
> noun
>
> 1. a depraved, unprincipled, or wicked person:

Some of these terms seem to be more gender specific, but I believe that the intended application would be understood regardless of gender. Though it is anachronistic, the essence of the description could be applied to any person acting as such.

Comment: Excellent answer! Now I remembered 'philanderer' -- thanks a lot, I updates!

Answer (score 0):

He has been cheating on his wife, he is a cad.

Comment: 'cad' is not a noun

Comment: @mitch, Yes it is.

Comment: He may be a cad, but not all cads are cheaters. He is equally a jerk, an asshole, a sleaze, scum, a heel, etc

Comment: Thank you @Lynn. (1) [google search for 'cad'](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=cad&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=RplKWdeYGPPH8gfj_5SoBA)    (2) https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cad

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New by logical extension could we say *all cheaters are cads but not all cads are cheaters?*

Comment: @EnglishStudent That depends on if you think cheating automatically makes you a cad, I guess. It's a subjective thing.

Comment: @Ben oops. haha. I can't read.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 cheating definitely makes you a cad. the question then is if being a cad necessarily means you were unfaithful. I'm having a hard time thinking of instances where not.

Comment: @Mitch _cad_ doesn't mean unfaithful. And labels like _cad_ don't encapsulate an entire person. A person can be faithful and be a cad, or have been unfaithful but otherwise be kind, generous, and trustworthy.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 OK. The first definition I saw (google definition cad) said ["a man who behaves dishonorably, especially toward a woman."](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cad) which is a sideways or weakened way of saying 'he was unfaithful'. But other dictionaries seem to qualify with different direction so as to not emphasize the, what I read to be, unfaithfulness.

Comment: @Lynn - Answers without explanations and citations are poor and are generally not well received on this site. Please edit in a definition of "cad" and explain why it is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, you might consider **rat**.

[Oxford dictionary online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rat):

> **rat**
>
> 2. *informal* A despicable person, especially a man who has been deceitful or disloyal.
>
> *‘her rat of a husband cheated on her’*

Comment: Thank you. I think 'rat' is applied to the person as meaning despicable *because* they cheated?

Answer (score -2):

New Oxford American Dictionary

**Fornicator** (noun): (of two people not married to each other) have sexual intercourse.

Comment: "Fornicator" doesn't imply any sort of unfaithfulness, though.